# In Java (7), how to get the value of an annotated field

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class with fields on which some are annotated with a custom annotation. i have a method that needs to retreive the value of those fields in an instantiated class:

```
public void displayStringValue(Row row)
    for (Field field : Row.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        SomeAnnotation annotatedElement = field.getAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
        if (annotatedElement != null) {
            row.getValue(field.getName()); // What to do here in stead of this?
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, `row.getValue(String fieldname);` does not exist. Here i need to find a way of getting the value of that field in row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to [`Field#get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) the value of the field for the given `Row` object?

```
field.setAccessible(true);
Object fieldValue = field.get(row); // or cast it if you know the type
```

[`setAccessible(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) is necessary if the field is not visible from the calling class.

Comment: Right, if the field is private. Though, depending on the context you may want to check if there's a getter method for such a field and invoke it instead. As accessing private fields directly somehow violates the contract and may break whatever logic implemented in the class. That's especially true for those trying to mimic immutable objects in Java (as in Scala).

Comment: @okiharaherbst If one really needs to get the value of a private field with the help of reflection, one usually follows the contract of the class anyway by doing so. Otherwise one is misusing this feature and has to live with the possible consequences. A good example for valid use would be the static `serialVersionUID` field of the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Comment: @Balder: `serialVersionUID` is `final` which makes it not only safe but also very legitimate to access the field directly. There are cases –with mutable classes– where one uses reflection to inspect the fields and then (again with reflection) finds the corresponding getters to invoke. All this reflectively, hence not known at compile-time.

Comment: @Balder: also, keep in mind that you may be working with a proxied instance, the logic of which will almost invariably break down if you fiddle with the fields directly.

Comment: @okiharaherbst You are of course right, but in the cases you mentioned, you are also following some contract - i.e. that some private field should always be accessed by a public getter, if this is possible. If you are on the other hand, for example, serializing/deserializing Objects and access their private instance fields while doing so, it is usually no good idea to access the fields through their public API. This is what I meant with `one usually follows the contract of the class anyway`.

Comment: @Balder: Definitely, you're preaching to the choir.